# Как найти все индексы вхождения подстроки в строку?

Tags: c#, строки

Как найти все индексы вхождения подстроки в строку, при этом не изменяя саму строку?

Comment: Регулярками. Там совпадения содержат позицию.

Comment: по-другому нельзя?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать перегрузку [`IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx), принимающую начальный индекс:

```
string source = "some source string";
string substring = "so";

var indices = new List<int>();

int index = source.IndexOf(substring, 0);
while (index > -1)
{    
    indices.Add(index);
    index = source.IndexOf(substring, index + substring.Length);
}
```

Comment: Бесконечный цикл. Переменная index всегда будет больше -1, так как она не изменяется

Comment: @РустемВалеев исправил.

Answer (score 0):

С данной задачей неплохо справится метод расширения для нахождения всех индексов вхождения:

```
public static List<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string value) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("the string to find may not be empty", "value");
    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
    for (int index = 0;; index += value.Length) {
        index = str.IndexOf(value, index);
        if (index == -1)
            return indexes;
        indexes.Add(index);
    }
}
```

Использовать метод довольно просто:

```
string dummyText = "blabla";
string substring = "b";
List<int> indexes = dummyText .AllIndexesOf(substring);
```

Главное не забыть поместить этот метод в статичный класс и указать пространство имён.